# NVS 4200m Not using all Shared system memory

Tags: display-driver

I have a laptop and it has the Nvidia NVS 4200m wich is 500Mb dedicated memory and 2GB Shared system memory how can i force my pc to use all of the Shared ssytem memory Becase it only using the 500Mb Amd i have 8GB of ram plz help thanks.

Comment: Usually by checking the driver settings or BIOS settings. Consider fixing the typos at the end of that paragraph. In addition check your manual. At least [this](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-NVS-4200M.47343.0.html) would suggest the card doesn't support shared memory and the [official](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvs_techspecs.html) page would suggest it only supports up to 1 GB memory.